# Android - move navigation drawer titles away from main activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I've been following this tutorial (http://codetheory.in/android-navigation-drawer/) to create a navigation drawer. I'd like to move the strings that populates the drawer outside the MainActivity, for instance to strings.xml

Here is the code that populates the drawer

```
    mNavItems.add(new NavItem("String 1", "", R.mipmap.ic_action_home));
    mNavItems.add(new NavItem("String 2", "", R.mipmap.ic_action_about));
    mNavItems.add(new NavItem("String 3", "", R.mipmap.ic_action_about));
    mNavItems.add(new NavItem("String 4", "", R.mipmap.ic_action_about));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your strings in strings.xml in values resource folder in your project.

It should should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="menu_item">Home</string>
</resources>
```

You can then reach it from code by doing by doing (note R.string, singular):

`getResources().getString(R.string.menu_item);`

Regards

Answer (score 0):

so put your strings in your strings.xml, and then do like that:

```
mNavItems.add(new NavItem(getString(R.strings.home)), "", R.mipmap.ic_action_home));
```

Comment: I'm getting a "Cannot resolve symbol" error under strings. strings.xml is under values, should it be somwhere else?

Comment: Solved with getResources().getString(R.string.home)